# Best way to count number of users in a Java EE web App

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, monitoring

What is the best way/pattern for counting the number of active users using a particular java EE JSF web app?

The two ways I know is HttpSessionListener and using JMX web beans, if there is a third better way I am open to suggestions. I am just trying to figure out the most elegant solution.

Help is much appreciated

Comment: "Using" at the same time? Over a period of time? Which?

Comment: What do you have? What frameworks / technologies are you using? A bit more about the technology stack, please.

Comment: If I an figure out how many users I have at a given instance (right now), I can save the data and calculate the number of users during a certain period easily. So to answer you question, Using right now (active users).... sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I dont understand why this got down voted?

Comment: @RegisteredUser It wasn't me, but usually you're downvoted when you don't provide enough information, your question is too vague, or the downvoter thinks that you could have done more research in this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to track the number of active users at the same time in simple Java web app built without using any frameworks , then the standard way to do that is to implement `HttpSessionListener` . Code below is just a reference to the way you can implement it .

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class ActiveUserCounter implements HttpSessionListener {  

      private static AtomicInteger activeSessions = new AtomicInteger();    

      public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {  
              activeSessions.incrementAndGet();  
      }  

      public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {  
                if(activeSessions.get() > 0)  
                       activeSessions.decrementAndGet();  
      }  

     public static int getActiveSessions() {  
             return activeSessions.get();  
      }   
}
```

Define the listener class in your web.xml .

Comment: That's a good idea if you are counting the active sessions. But we still don't know that the OP wants.

Comment: That is the reason I started my answer with *"If you want to track the number of active users at the same time"* !

Comment: +1 for your answer, I think GaborSch was right I am unclear, I was thinking about HttpSessionListener and then heard about JMX and trying to find the best way .. I will wait for other users to answer if they have any good suggestions.. thanks for your input though

Comment: Then this might be of help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112381/getting-active-session-counts-with-jmx-java-management-extensions-api